# iphone, how to call the struct members

Tags: iphone, struct

my ManageMarketPacket.h has a struct,like follow:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
typedef struct ORIGINAL_QUOTA_DATA_tag{
    unsigned short  id;
    unsigned char   exch;          
}ORIGINAL_QUOTA_DATA;
@end
```

and in ManageMarketPacket.m had a function intending to get the id:

```
- (unsigned short)getId:(NetWorkConnect*)netWokrConnect{
   //I want to get the id which have assigend in netWokrConnect.m  
   //I tried "return (netWokrConnect->oQuota).id; "is incorrect  
}
```

and in my NetWorkConnect.h,I defined the struct:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ManageMarketPacket.h"
@interface NetWorkConnect : NSObject{    
    ORIGINAL_QUOTA_DATA oQuota;    
}
```

in NetWorkConnect.m,I assigned the oQuota.and in another file,i call the function  getId;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things you need to change in order to get this working.

1. First of all, you need to change your Structure because you are using a variable name `id` and `id` is a reserved Objective-C keyword. I changed it to `identifier` and you'll need to change any methods which use the variable

   ```
   typedef struct ORIGINAL_QUOTA_DATA_tag {
      unsigned short  identifier;
      unsigned char   exch;          
   } ORIGINAL_QUOTA_DATA;
   ```
2. In your NetworkConnect class, you need to add a @property and @synthesize for your oQuota variable so you can access it from other classes like so:

   In **NetworkConnect.h**

   ```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
   #import "ManageMarketPacket.h"
   @interface NetWorkConnect : NSObject{    
       ORIGINAL_QUOTA_DATA oQuota;    
   }

   @property (readwrite, assign) ORIGINAL_QUOTA_DATA oQuota;
   ```

   In **NetworkConnect.m**

   ```
   @implementation NetworkConnect
   @synthesize oQuota;

       // Rest of your Implementation here...

   @end
   ```
3. To access the `oQuota` variable in your method. You need to change it like so:

   ```
   - (unsigned short)getId:(NetWorkConnect*)netWokrConnect{
        // I want to get the identifer which have assigend in netWokrConnect.m  
        netWokrConnect->oQuota.identifer;
   }
   ```

   Alternatively you can use the `.` dot syntax as well which is what I prefer like so:

   ```
   - (unsigned short)getId:(NetWorkConnect*)netWokrConnect{
        // I want to get the identifer which have assigend in netWokrConnect.m  
        netWokrConnect.oQuota.identifer;
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you very much,but there is a little problem,the "->" will get warning"Instance variable'oQuota' is protected",but the dot is correct.thank you again....

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make a property out of `oQuota` to make it visible outside the class that defines it. Then you can simply call it like this: netWorkConnect.oQuota.id